# return optional from generic function in c++

Tags: c++, templates

What's another way to return generic optional in c++, without using the `optional<T>{} from BOOST library`

## Example

```
 template<class T>
    T search(T arg) {
        // this function is just to show the idea of what I am trying to ac
       if (found) return arg;
       return ?<---
    }
```

I mean if I know the most common type that will call this function I could

**return T(-1);** for int

**return T("not found");** for string

**return nullprt;** for pointer type

But that defeat the purpose of generic. There must be another way right ?
Thanks for helping

Comment: How could an existing facility possibly know a good default for every type?

Comment: are you referring the three returns example ?

Comment: Yes, it sounded like you wanted that, but generic.

Comment: yeah sir, i was even thinking to have these returns inside some dictionary then detect which type was passing in the return value for that specific key

Comment: Yet you can't possibly do this for every type. I have my own type written after your generic code. How would it even know how to construct an object of my type, let alone construct a reasonable one for returning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, `boost::optional` or `std::optional` were made exactly for that case. Is there a reason why you don't want to use them? Because most solutions will either mimic `std::optional` or they are a poor replacement.

## Pass an output parameter by reference.

```
template <class T>
bool search( T arg, T & out );
```

Returns whether it has written the result to out or not. This can be a poor replacement because it requires the caller to construct an object of type `T`. If the caller itself is generic, then `T` either must be default-constructible or passed to the caller itself.

## If you would usually return a reference, return a pointer instead.

```
template <class T>
const T & search( T arg );
```

can be replaced with

```
template <class T>
const T * search( T arg );
```

Please note, that `std::optional` does not support references to the same extent as `boost::optional`, so when using `std::optional`, you may really fall back to this when dealing with references.

## Write an optional yourself.

I wouldn't recommend this. You have to put a lot of thought into it if you want to do it right. If you can live with the constraints of `boost::optional` or `std::optional` (in particular regarding thread-safety) I can't see a reason why you should to this.

## Have a type trait that provides dummy values.

Reading your question again, you thought about keeping dummy values in a map. I would not recommend this, because, obviously, it is less generic and I can't see any benefits. But regarding the map, you would have a type trait that provides dummy values:

```
template <class T>
struct DummyValue;

template <>
struct DummyValue<int>
{
    static constexpr const int value = -1;
    // Or:
    // static int makeDummyValue();
};
// And so on ...
```

Comment: you are right... optional library it is lol... thanks for explaining... man they need to ship c++ with std::optional man